# Json deserialization Java

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization

i have a simple question, let's say I have this json

```json
{
   "outer-field":{
      "outer-a":"something",
      "outer-b":12345678,
      "inner-field":{
         "inner-a":false,
         "inner-b":0.0,
         "inner-c":29.99
      }
   }
}
```

Mapped this way:

```java
public class OuterObject {

    @JsonProperty("outer-a")
    public String outerA;
   
    @JsonProperty("outer-b")
    public Integer outerB;
   
    @JsonProperty("inner-field")
    public InnerObject innerField;

}

public class InnerObject{

    @JsonProperty("inner-a")
    public Boolean innerA;

    @JsonProperty("inner-b")
    public Double innerB;

    @JsonProperty("inner-c")
    public Double innerC;
```

I was wondering if it was possible to just save an outer field in the inner object like this by using some custom setter/annotation or something:

```java
public class InnerObject{

    @JsonProperty("inner-a")
    public Boolean innerA;

    @JsonProperty("inner-b")
    public Double innerB;

    @JsonProperty("inner-c")
    public Double innerC;

    //how to map this?
    @JsonProperty("outer-a")
    public String outerA;
```

PS: using a custom deserialization is my last resort due to the complexity of the json

Comment: You could first deserialize to the outer and inner objects as usual, and then map it to a different object using MapStruct.

Comment: The question would be, why do you want/need this? You have the fully mapped JSON to POJO, that contains all the fields you want. If you wish to ignore the other fields from `outer`, you can trim down the POJO and disable `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone was asking how I solve my problem, I decided to use a custom Builder by using the withXXX methods inside to pass the outer attributes to the inner object during creation

```java
@Jacksonized
@JsonDeserialize(builder = OuterObject.Builder.class)
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class OuterObject {

    public String outerA;
    public Integer outerB;
    public InnerObject innerObject;

    public static class Builder {

        public String outerA;
        public Integer outerB;
        public InnerObject innerObject;

        Builder withInnerObject(InnerObject innerObject) {
            // set attributes here
            innerObject.outerA = this.outerA
            this.innerObject = innerObject
            return this;
        }

        public OuterObject build() {
            return new(outerA, outerB, innerObject)
        }

Hope someone might find this helpful
```